# Filtering rows of dataframe based on quintiles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a dataframe using the following code. I am triong to create a new dataframe that contains only rows from the original dataframe that are less than or greater than Q1 or Q4 for each PP.

I tried `filtered_df = df[df['Hours per action'].lt(first_quartile) | df['Hours per action'].gt(fourth_quartile)]`, but that isn't right. I need all rows with 'PP' == 1 to use the Q1 and Q4 from 'PP' 1, all rows with 'PP' == 2 to use the Q1 and Q4 from 'PP' 2, and so on. Thank you

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of all possible combinations of 'PP' and 'Name'
pp_employee_combinations = [(pp, name) for pp in range(1, 27) for name in ['Wyatt', 'Thom', 'Pete', 'Sue', 'Dave']]

# Create a new DataFrame with all of the possible combinations of 'PP' and 'Name'
df = pd.DataFrame(pp_employee_combinations, columns=['PP', 'Name'])

import numpy.random as rnd

# Fill in the 'Hours per action' column with random values
df['Hours per action'] = rnd.randint(10, 100, size=df.shape[0])

Q1 = df.groupby('PP')['Hours per action'].quantile(0.25)
Q4 = df.groupby('PP')['Hours per action'].quantile(0.75)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the transform method along with `groupby` to broadcast the computed Q1 and Q4 values to each row.
After that, you can use `boolean` indexing to filter the rows accordingly. you can achieve this like:

```
df['Q1'] = df.groupby('PP')['Hours per action'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.25))
df['Q4'] = df.groupby('PP')['Hours per action'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.75))

filtered_df = df[(df['Hours per action'] < df['Q1']) | (df['Hours per action'] > df['Q4'])]

filtered_df = filtered_df.drop(columns=['Q1', 'Q4'])
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `map` and `between` to select the relevant rows:

```
>>> df[df["Hours per action"].between(df["PP"].map(Q1),df["PP"].map(Q4))]
```